# Use django-oauth-plus with Tastypie

Tags: django, oauth, tastypie

I try to use tastypie with django-oauth-plus. I follow wiki page of django-oauth-plus: http://code.larlet.fr/django-oauth-plus/wiki/Home and set resource authentication in tastypie to OAuthAuthentication. In step 'Obtaining a Request Token' i get error 400 (Could not verify OAuth request.)

I check https://github.com/amrox/django-api-example to to see anything I have not forgotten, but it not help.

Can anyone help me? I not know how to debug it :(

Thank you!

**UPD:**

I try to get access and provide access from one website. May be problem with it?